# after installing java 8, javac -version works on my mac but not java -version

Tags: java, macos, jvm, homebrew

I'm experiencing some difficulty setting up my **java 8** dev environment on my macbook pro **OS 10.10.5**

In the terminal I executed the below:

```
brew update
brew cask install java --force
```

after the above steps were complete, it says:

> java was successfully installed!

Now I need to figure out how to setup my JAVA_HOME variables in .bash_profile.

But I'm seeing the below weird situation:

```
petesp$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_102
```

But what the heck is going on below and why? How do I setup the JAVA_HOME on my MAC for java 8?

```
petesp$ java -version
-bash: java: command not found
```

Why is the java -version not found? thats totally weird. If I used brew to install java, I'm assuming both javac -version and java -version should run correctly.

Comment: Is java in your path? Have you installed JRE?

Comment: It is weird that the # is in that error output. What's the output of `which javac` and `which java`?

Comment: ohh no, that #, those are my comments!

Comment: @JasonC- there is no output for `which java` and `which javac`

Comment: when I run `which javac`, it returns: `/usr/bin/javac` but running `which java` it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

This script enables you to switch between **Java 1.7** and **Java 1.8** and also set JDK on your bash profile.

Insert the below code block in your .bashrc or .bash_profile scripts in your home directory.

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
 }
function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
}
```

For JDK 1.7:

```
#set default jdk version
setjdk 1.7.0_60
```

Once you have set up your bash startup scripts. You can use the following commands to switch between versions in your command line.

To switch to Java 1.7 and verify your version. Run the following commands.

```
$ setjdk 1.7
$ java -version
```

Output:

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

To switch back to Java 1.8 and verify your version. Run the following commands.

```
$ setjdk 1.8
```

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Do I need to run .bash_profile? Not sure how this is done on mac. I tried to run setjdk 1.8, but the output was `command not found.`

Comment: @user836087 You will need to add this to the ./bash_profile.

Comment: I did that. It doesn't work. `setjdk 1.8
-bash: setjdk: command not found`

Comment: @user836087 Ok. Just try running this: export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Comment: That didn't do it. There seems to be some other issue. when I run `which javac`, it returns: `/usr/bin/javac` but running `which java` it doesn't return anything

Comment: As part of setting up my env for my new job they wanted me to execute `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/java`. I think this screwed things up. How can I revert this?

Comment: @user836087 Ok. Once deleted it can't be retrieved. I guess, you will need to start over again. Download jdk and install it again.